# Problems With Search Engine Friendly Urls

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, seo

I have been trying for ages to rewrite my urls so that they are SEO friendly. It is by far the hardest quest i have ever encountered in my time developing websites and still nothing works.

I have my link setup like this

```
<a href="view_portfolio.php?portid=<?php echo $row_portfolio['portid']; ?>" class="purpletoblacklink">Read On
```

and my htacess setup like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /portid/(.*)$ /page/view_portfolio.php?portid=$1
```

basically following what every tutorial on the subject has told developers to do.

This is the first time,i am posting a question on any forum whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

One important point most mod_rewrite tutorials don’t mention is: mod_rewrite rewrites requests and not responses.

So if you put `foobar.php` in your HTML document, your browser will request `foobar.php` even if you have a rule that rewrites requests of *quux* internally to *foobar.php* as it’s `foobar.php` that the HTML document refers to.

In your case you already need to serve the HTML document linking to `/portid/…`:

```
<a href="/portid/<?php echo $row_portfolio['portid']; ?>" class="purpletoblacklink">Read On
```